# Adding a broadcast receiver to bind with an external USB device

Tags: android, usb, broadcastreceiver, nfc

I'm building an app that interacts with a USB NFC reader (for devices that don't have native NFC).  The receiver is USB and comes with an nice SDK which seems to work as advertised (in that I can successfully read the tags that are swiped past the reader).

My challenge that I believe should be pretty straight forward but am unclear on how to implement is how to register my app to be notified when the USB attached NFC reader is triggered by the proximity of an NFC tag.

Do I just register a broadcast receiver that calls something like:

```
UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

and launch my app myself?  Somehow that doesn't feel right.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a BroadcastReceiver registered in the manifest. This will allow your application to be notified even if it isn't running.

```
public class NfcReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    /* ... */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs =_
              intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
        } /* end handle NDEF_DISCOVERED */
    } /* end onReceive */
} /* end BroadcastReceiver*/
```

In your manifest, be sure to add the proper intent filters (I've never done NFC, but I believe this is correct to get you started:)

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<receiver android:name=".NfcReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html

There are also solutions out there if you can/desire to go that route, for example:

http://mobisocial.github.com/EasyNFC/apidocs/reference/mobisocial/nfc/Nfc-source.html

Comment: I don't see ACTION_HANDLE_NDEF as a possible option when eclipse offers hints.  Where can I verify if that flag actually exists?

Comment: Sorry, that permission is actually specific to the EasyNfc library referenced. Updated sample code and added links.